# Gradle Launch4j: Can't create Launch4jLibraryTask due to Project.afterEvaluate error

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, launch4j

I'm using the Gradle Kotlin DSL with the plugin `id("edu.sc.seis.launch4j") version "2.5.4"`

I can create one Launch4j executable with no problem with a `launch4j{}` block, but when I try to create a second one with the `Launch4jLibraryTask`

```
tasks.register<Launch4jLibraryTask>("createSecondExe") {
    //implementation 
}
```

I get the following error

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task 'createAllExecutables'.
> Could not create task 'createSecondExe'.
   > Could not create task of type 'Launch4jLibraryTask'.
      > Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.
```

I can see [in their repo here](https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j/blob/edcfaed4247a4f0f8ef3cc7c935bd2d877627c9c/src/main/groovy/edu/sc/seis/launch4j/tasks/DefaultLaunch4jTask.groovy#L43) that Project.afterEvaluate() is run when creating the task. But is there any way to avoid this error? It's failing on the creation of the task. This one has really got me stumped.

I'm following these inscructions: https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j#launch4jlibrarytask

Any advice? Thank you in advance.